# How does Android system handle activities when it is stopped?

Tags: android, lru, android-lru-cache

I am so curious about what will happen for the app's activities when the app is dismissed from the screen and the user switches to other apps. In the activity circle, the activity will reach onStop(), then how the system handle the activity before it is either onRestart() or relaunch? What exactly happens under the hood? Still in cache, replaced by LRU?

Anyone has some ideas or knows some articles discussing this issue?

If possible, can anyone mention some source code to read about that?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you get familiar with Android's Activity lifecycle. Depending on system needs, an activity may either be paused or stopped->destroyed once it is dismissed from the user's view. Have a look at this page
http://developer.android.com/images/activity_lifecycle.png

Comment: I guess my question lies in how the system handle the activity from it is stopped to onRestart() or being destroyed till relaunch. What exactly happens in the system.